# Unable to parse text from a file using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

Here is the line in a file I want to extract information from:

```
backup-initiation-time="00:00" backup-directory-path="/store/backup" backup-retention-period-days="2"
```

My command is:

```
grep "backup-directory-path" test.txt | sed 's/.*backup-directory-path="\(.*?\)" /\1/'
```

I just want `/store/backup` that's it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You want to display it?

Comment: For now actually its part of script, it will be saved in variable the grep cmd output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\K` (keep) and simply:

```
grep -oP '.*backup-directory-path=\K([^ ])+'
```

This will display only the captured part after the "keep".

In order to remove the quotes you have there, just modify it:

```
grep -oP '.*backup-directory-path="\K([^"])+'
```

Comment: Excellent, I want to drop the quotes " as well. It currently shows in your cmd.

Comment: @asad I don't get you.. can you please explain more?

Comment: To strip the quotes, just do analogically `grep -oP '.*backup-directory-path="\K([^"])+'`

Comment: @asad It means "ignore whatever appears before it, and only consider the group after it".

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any documentation on non-greedy matching in sed so I'm not sure if this was implemented.

Instead of your non-greedy match using `.*?` you could use `[^"]*` if you know the last or one past last character you want to match, in your case `"`.

This command produces the expected output:

```
grep "backup-directory-path" test.txt | sed 's|.* backup-directory-path="\([^"]*\)".*|\1|'
```